# Can i rearrange icons at android home screen by code

Tags: android

So, i want to make an application that will rearrange user's home screen icons. All i need is to know is it possible to move an icon **WITHOUT ROOT**. I need to change any icon's position for any application already installed.

I've searched on stackoverflow, but seems like there is no answer for this exactly question. If there is, please give me the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> i want to make an application that will rearrange user's home screen icons

There are hundreds, if not thousands, of launcher applications available for Android. This includes both pre-installed ones and user-installed ones. It is possible that some of those have an SDK with an API that allows third-party apps to manipulate the way the home screen is rendered. I am not aware of any that do, and I strongly suspect that very few do.

> All i need is to know is it possible to move an icon WITHOUT ROOT.

Unless the launcher app has an API, you have no means of affecting how the launcher app renders the home screen.

Comment: So you mean that android system doesn't provide a single solution for arranging icons on home screen and everything, that i may have seen is some kind of launcher? So if i need to rearrange icons by code in my own way i need to make my own launcher in this purpose, right? If so, maybe you know some articles with information that may help with it, thx

Comment: @Danissimo: "So you mean that android system doesn't provide a single solution for arranging icons on home screen and everything" -- correct. "So if i need to rearrange icons by code in my own way i need to make my own launcher in this purpose, right?" -- I guess so. Bear in mind that creating a full-featured launcher, with a home screen, app drawer, app widget support, and so on, is fairly complicated. Some developers do it, but it is not something that you will learn from an article.